# System.IndexOutOfRangeException when trying to save results from a stored proecedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a SQL Server stored procedures with this output:

```
unit_id     on_date             notes   type_code   type_order  status  (No column name)    (No column name)
3       2016-12-08 00:00:00.000             AVL             -1      D   NULL                 16
3       2016-12-08 00:00:00.000             RSU             1       D   3                     2
3       2016-12-08 00:00:00.000             TOW             2       D   6                     5
.......etc
```

What I am trying to do it get these rows a columns to I can display them in a grid (spreadsheet like) view, and use them as variables in a bar graph.

I've tried the code (in my controller)

```
var model = new List<ResultsModel>();

SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand("dbo.pr_name");

command3.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@from", SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime, Value = NowDate });
command3.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@to", SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime, Value = "2017-09-21 00:00:00" });
command3.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@method", SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, Value = 3 });
command3.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

using (var SPOutput3 = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    model.Add(new ResultsModel()
                {
                    unit_id = (Int32)SPOutput3["unit_id"],
                    on_date = (DateTimeOffset)SPOutput3["on_date"],
                    notes = SPOutput3["notes"].ToString(),
                    type_code = (string)SPOutput3["type_code"]
                    // other properties
                });
    return View(model);
}
```

and in my view

```
@*@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.on_date</td>
        <td>@item.type_code</td>
    </tr>
}*@
```

The code breaks at the line:

```
unit_id = (Int32)SPOutput3["unit_id"],
```

with an error `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`.

If I comment out that line, the error moves onto the next one etc.

The advise was after is: is the error telling me that there is no columns called unit_id in the output received? even thought the output from the SSMS shows it?
.. and what I can do to fix this?

Also....if the column has no name, how can I assign it ..like unit_id, on_date etc ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, first off, you need to call `Read` in a while loop:

```
using (var SPOutput3 = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (SPOutput3.Read())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, inside the while loop, you're dealing with an individual row. So you can do:

```
while (SPOutput3.Read())
{
    var unit_id = SPOutput3["unit_id"] as int?;
}
```

You want to use `as` rather than a direct cast here so you can stave off potential issues if bad data is returned or the type isn't what you think it is. If you need a non-nullable value, then you can simply use the null coalesce operator to provide a default:

```
SPOutput3["unit_id"] as int? ?? 0;
```

Comment: HO @Chris Pratt, Thank for the help. If I'm dealing with individual rows in the While loop, how can I reference specific detail when in the view ? as there will be different on_date, type_order etc values per row.

Comment: also,  `Column1 = SPOutput3["Column1"] as int? ?? 0 ` or  `Column2 = SPOutput3["Column2"] as int? `give me the error message **System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Column1'**.. and I only get the first row or results, not the other 141. thanks